# Maven removes WEB-INF folder and creates jsp folder

Tags: java, jsp, maven

I am working on a JAX-RS based webservice, which is build using maven. However if I build the project using maven my *WEB-INF* folder at *src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/* is removed and a new folder named *jsp* is created. Could this be a side effect of a maven plugin? Please find my `pom.xml` attached.

**pom.xml**

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.avedo.spozz</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spozz-Webservice</artifactId>
    <name>Spozz REST Webservice</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>${jettison.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- RESTEasy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- slf4j and log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.http.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL and OrmLite -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${ormlite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>spozz</finalName>

        <!-- Directories to be filtered by resources plugin -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>surefire-it</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Load properties for database connections -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>src/main/resources/psql-custom.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Setup of jetty -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>

                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>9095</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sql.maven.plugin.version}</version>

                <!-- Specify the dependent jdbc driver -->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- Common configuration shared by all executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <driver>${database.jdbc.driverClass}</driver>
                    <url>${database.jdbc.connectionURL}</url>
                    <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have 
                        maven to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
                    <username>${database.jdbc.username}</username>
                    <password>${database.jdbc.password}</password>
                    <settingsKey>postgres-db</settingsKey>
                    <!-- All executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>drop-db-before-test-if-any</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- need another database to drop the targeted one -->
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432</url>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>DROP DATABASE ${database.jdbc.dbName};</sqlCommand>
                            <!-- ignore error when database is not available -->
                            <onError>continue</onError>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>create-db</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432</url>
                            <!-- no transaction -->
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>CREATE DATABASE ${database.jdbc.dbName};</sqlCommand>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>create-tables</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <delimiterType>row</delimiterType>
                            <srcFiles>
                                <srcFile>src/main/sql/spozz-schema.sql</srcFile>
                            </srcFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-3</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- Common configuration shared by all executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <driver>${database.jdbc.driverClass}</driver>
                    <url>${database.jdbc.connectionURL}</url>
                    <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have 
                        maven to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
                    <username>${database.jdbc.username}</username>
                    <password>${database.jdbc.password}</password>
                    <settingsKey>postgres-db</settingsKey>
                    <!-- All executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven dependency plugin for downloading and copying dependencies -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.dependency.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven resource plugin for resource filtering -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.resources.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Deployment profiles -->
    <profiles>
        ...
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you using maven-dependency-plugin? What are you using maven-surefire-plugin for integration testing? There is a better one: maven-failsafe-plugin which is intended for integration testing. Furthermore what does it mean 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF' is removed?  How do you call mvn? `mvn clean package`?

Comment: I am using the maven-dependency-plugin to automatically load needed dependencies. The maven-surefire-plugin is used to run jUnit tests. I build the service using the following command: `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -P devProfile`

Comment: You don't need dependency plugin to download dependencies. If you defined your dependencies correct it will be done automatically. If you really run unit test and *no* integration test it does not make sense to bind maven-surefre-plugin to integration test life cycle phase.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Removed both plugins (`maven-dependency-plugin` and `maven-surefire-plugin`). Worked without problems during tests and build, but problem was not solved.

Comment: Furthermore what does it mean 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF' is removed?

Comment: It is deleted. When I run `mvn clean install`the package is build and the *WEB-INF* directory is deleted. If I then build the project again, maven complains about this missing directory.

Comment: Something is deleted in `src/main/`? Really. Than you didn't show the full pom file.